# How are customers coming through as "Guest"?

Tags: onepage-checkout, customer-account

Once a week we will have customers purchase through our site, but the account information comes through as:

Customer name: Guest
Email: ______ (blank)
Customer Group: Taxable

Any thoughts on how this is happening? Email and Name are required fields for guests or account users.

Comment: A screenshot would be more helpful. It's not very clear "coming through" means.

Comment: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a74pvav6e

Comment: When I say coming through, I mean when looking at the sales order the account information shows up with Customer Name: Guest, Email: (Blank). We get these once a week and have no idea how it's possible as these are required fields and have no problem with 99% of other orders

Comment: Have you looked up the corresponding order records in the database?

Comment: The issue is that we tie our orders to Celigo and push to netsuite. The name and email field are required in NetSuite as well so we get error messages and have to place them in manually. We have their email and their name elsewhere in the order, but this account area is how it's mapped and no one should be checking out completely as "Guest"

Comment: I'm asking if you've checked `sales_flat_order.customer_*` fields in the DB.

Comment: I don't know where or what that is.